# What does this symbol mean on my Samsung travel adapter?

Tags: power-supply, power, adapter

The charger was bought in Austria two years ago, and I know about all symbols/labels except this one. Google reverse image search did not help.

[image]

Comment: _Thank You_ for asking this. I've wondered about this for ages and never managed the right Google Fu to find the answer.

Comment: That's the Dinosaur footprint - means your travel adapter is also rated for time-travel... **but only backwards in time**.  Device is not approved for time-travel forward to the future, else it would also have the Jetsons bubble-car image.

Comment: @Criggie, if time travel forward has the Jetson's car, why wouldn't backwards have the Flintstone's car? (Hint: same production firm of Hanna-Barbera, and one episode of Jetsons shows Elroy watching the Flintstones on his TV watch.) Maybe that's a new question. lol

Answer (score 81):

[image]

That's the [Ukrsepro mark](https://gma.ul.com/about/globalmarkets/ukraine/). It means the product has passed the [certification of UkrSEPRO](https://www.szutest.com/international-certification/ukrsepro/), the safety certification requirement symbol for trading in the Ukraine region.

> Scope of products covered by the above regulations include but not
>   limited to the following:
>
> - Information technology equipment
> - Audio and video equipment
> - Household and similar use appliances
> - Lighting products
> - Electric tools
> - Low-voltage electrical equipment
> - Electrical wires and cables
> - Switches for circuits, installation protective and connection devices
> - Telecommunication terminal equipment
> - Manufacturing equipment for food, meat, dairy industry, trade enterprises, catering and food processing enterprises
>     Electrical machinery

The norms and standards products have to comply by are set by the Ukrainian Research and Training Center of Standardization, Certification and Quality Issues (UkrNDNC, a state enterprise), the Ukraine representative for ISO, IEC, CEN, CENELEC, ETSI etc. Also known as [DSTU](https://www.iso.org/member/2172.html).

Importers and manufacturers are allowed to prove conformity by submitting self-declaration (like CE in Europe). However, this declaration must additionally be registered with the accredited authority (regulated by the National Accreditation Agency of Ukraine, NAAU). See also the [EC Trade Market Access Database, paragraph "Standardisation" on Ukraine](https://madb.europa.eu/madb/viewPageIFPubli.htm?doc=overview&countryid=UA#h34).

Likely (thanks to [dlatikay](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/113649/dlatikay) for pointing out the obvious), the symbol represents a tryzub, a trident prominent on the [Ukrainian Coat of Arms](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Lesser_Coat_of_Arms_of_Ukraine.svg) and which has been important [throughout Ukrainian history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAk2H.jpg).

Comment: I love how Czech and Slovakia _need_ to have it _a bit_ different :)

Comment: Youre my new hero! **Note that these marks are *not* equivalent.  Almost any cheap Cheese junk has a faked CE or CCC mark. FCC and RoHS have nothing to do with electrical safety.** A USA agency called OSHA curates a list of trusted testing labs (NRTL), and many agencies and countries defer to that list. An important feature of reputable marks is the **file number**, a 4-8 digit number corresponding to the lab testing which certified the appliance.